# Find constants using the mean, variance and covariance of two random variables

Tags: probability

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)=a+bX$, find $a$ and $b$ in terms of the mean, the variance and the covariance of $X$ and $Y$.

Hint: What is the relationship between the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ and the covariance between $\mathbb{E}(Y\mid X)$ and $X$.

I don't see how to use the hint. Maybe use the law of total covariance? But I don't have $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$E(Y)= E[E(Y|X)]\\ \implies E(Y)= a+b \cdot E(X)$$
Also
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X,Y) &= E(XY)- E(X)\cdot E(Y)\\ \implies\text{Cov}(X,Y)+E(X)\cdot E(Y) &= E[E(XY|X)] \\ \implies\text{Cov}(X,Y)+E(X)\cdot E(Y) &= E[X\cdot E(Y|X)]\\ \implies\text{Cov}(X,Y)+E(X)\cdot E(Y) &= a\cdot E(X)+ b\cdot E(X^2)\\ \implies\text{Cov}(X,Y)+E(X)\cdot E(Y) &= a\cdot E(X)+ b\cdot (\text{Var}(X)+E^2(X))
\end{align}
From these two equations you will get $a$ and $b$ in terms of the mean, the variance and the covariance of $X$ and $Y$.